# Principal Already Exist LDAP C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, ldap-query, principalcontext

I am trying to update a user on Active Directory using MVC C# LDAP, if a user is already in groups I remove him first from the group and add him again using Principal context. I tried to commit changes at the end of my remove loop but this did not help

Here is my code remove code:

```
PropertyValueCollection groups = result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["memberOf"];
                if (groups != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < groups.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string groupDn = (string)groups[i];

                        DirectoryEntry group = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + groupDn, null, null);
                        if (group != null)
                        {
                            group.Invoke("Remove", new object[] { result.Path });
                        }
                        group.CommitChanges();
                    }
                }
```

code to add user to groups

```
    //DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(groupDirectoryEntry);
                using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, AD_Address))// "10.125.153.30"))
                {
                    foreach (var rights in accessGroupList)
                    {
                        GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, rights);
                        group.Members.Add(pc, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, model.validPersalNumber); //this is where is failes
                        group.Save();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I'm curious: why are you removing the user from the group, then adding it back to the same group?

Comment: @GabrielLuci I have an interface whereby a call center agent has to choose access (E.g Country, Provincial, National , Own department) level and application (Finance ,HR ,Report) so in some case you might find that they want to revoke access or edit rights.  When I googled for solutions most solution suggested that I remove the user from group(s) and add him again.

Comment: Removing and re-adding to the same group won't have any effect - at least not in AD itself. Do you have some other application that is reading group membership and somehow resets when you remove and re-add a group?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question very well however we have a web application that people log into using AD details and granting them access to files based on the access right they have in AD and the application. I am still new to AD so I know minimal info about AD

Answer (score 0):

on remove group code after commit change, I had to close group

```
 PropertyValueCollection groups = result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["memberOf"];
                if (groups != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < groups.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string groupDn = (string)groups[i];

                        DirectoryEntry group = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + groupDn, null, null);
                        if (group != null)
                        {
                            group.Invoke("Remove", new object[] { result.Path });
                        }
                        group.CommitChanges();
                        group.Close();
                    }
```